# How to animate text gradient color change in Tailwind?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have a div with text inside that has a gradient color scheme.

```
<div
      className="bg-gradient-to-r bg-clip-text text-transparent from-indigo-500 to-purple-500"
    >
      SampleText
</div>
```

I want to animate it so that the gradient keeps smoothly changing between `from-indigo-500 to-purple-500` and `from-purple-500 to-indigo-500` infinitely with a set duration.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a simple way to achieve what you want, here is how :

1- First go to *tailwind.config.js* and add this inside *extend*

```
 extend: {
      'animation': {
            'text':'text 5s ease infinite',
        },
        'keyframes': {
            'text': {
                '0%, 100%': {
                   'background-size':'200% 200%',
                    'background-position': 'left center'
                },
                '50%': {
                   'background-size':'200% 200%',
                    'background-position': 'right center'
                }
            },
        }
    },
```

2- Then add these classes to your div :

```
<div class="text-9xl font-semibold 
            bg-gradient-to-r bg-clip-text  text-transparent 
            from-indigo-500 via-purple-500 to-indigo-500
            animate-text
            ">
      SampleText
</div>
```

Take a look **[HERE](https://play.tailwindcss.com/5nzLKbNPD9)**

Comment: This does animate a color change, however there no longer is a gradient on the text.

Comment: oh sorry, I didn't totally get it, my bad. I will update my answer have a look now.

Comment: change ```via-purple-500``` to ```via-green-500``` so you could see the animation clearly

Comment: @mismaah I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an alternative to the config approach, I use CSS to extend the "tailwindcss/components" import in your global styles.

In your global.css add the following.
Checkout the following link for more info on working with preprocessors - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors

```
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "./custom-components.css"; <--
```

Inside custom-components.css add the following.

```
.background-animate {
  background-size: 200%;
  -webkit-animation: AnimateBackgroud 10s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: AnimateBackgroud 10s ease infinite;
  animation: AnimateBackgroud 10s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes AnimateBackgroud {
  0% {
    background-position: 0;
  }

  50% {
    background-position: 100%;
  }

   100% {
    background-position: 0;
  }
}
```

How to use;

```
<h1 className="background-animate bg-gradient-to-r from-indigo-500 via-purple-500 to-pink-500 bg-clip-text flex justify-center items-center content-center w-full text-transparent text-5xl select-none">
    A very important title!
</h1>
```

```css
.background-animate {
  background-size: 200%;
  -webkit-animation: AnimateBackgroud 10s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: AnimateBackgroud 10s ease infinite;
  animation: AnimateBackgroud 10s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes AnimateBackgroud {
  0% {
    background-position: 0;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="min-h-full flex items-center justify-center p-12">
    <div class="max-w-md w-full">
      <h1 class="background-animate bg-gradient-to-r from-indigo-500 via-green-500 to-pink-500 bg-clip-text flex justify-center items-center content-center w-full text-transparent text-5xl select-none py-10">
        A very important title!
      </h1>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```